# SQL query that joins two tables and sum from second

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this tables with example data:

**Calendar**

```
ID | Date          
---+-----------
1  | 2020-01-01   
2  | 2020-01-02 
3  | 2020-01-03
```

**EmployeeTimeWorked**

```
ID | Date       | HoursWorked  | UserID
---+------------+--------------+-------
1  | 2020-01-01 | 2            | 2
2  | 2020-01-01 | 4            | 2
```

I want to make a MS-SQL query that shows days the user have not worked, and how many hours they have left to work (they should work 8 hours per day). All within within a time period, say a week.
The result should look like this:

**EmployeeHaveNotWorked**

```
Date       | HoursLeftToWork
-----------+----------------
2020-01-01 | 2
```

Any idea how to make such a MS-SQL Query?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate all possible rows and then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select u.userid, c.date,
       8 - coalesce(sum(HoursWorked), 0) as remaining_time
from calendar c cross join
     (select distinct userid from EmployeeTimeWorked) u left join
     EmployeeTimeWorked etw
     on etw.userid = u.userid and etw.date = c.date
where etw.userid is null
group by u.userid, c.date
having sum(HoursWorked) < 8
```

Comment: Good answer, but there is an aggregation missing. In the example, the user #2 worked twice on 2020-01-01. One time two hours, the other four hours. 8 - (2+4) = 2. We must hence outer join the aggregated work times per user and day.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and so fast! How would that query look?

Comment: @Olof84: You'd mainly replace `EmployeeTimeWorked` with a subquery in which you add up working times per user and date, i.e. something along the lines of `from (select ...) subq` and then add the desired math to your select clause (8hrs-sum).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . The `where` clause would filter out two records just as easily as it would filter out one record.

Comment: I am not sure how you mean, could you write the query?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Yep, sorry, I see now that your query addresses the first part (missing dates) and not the second (missing hours), which you have probably overlooked in the request.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . I see.  I missed that part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

First get all users with all dates. This is done with a cross join. Seeing that you are using a `UserID` I suppose there is a users table. Otherwise get the users from the `EmployeeTimeWorked` table.

Then outer join the working times per user and date. This is a simple aggregation query.

Then subtract the worked hours from the required 8 hours.

```
select 
  u.userid, 
  c.date,
  8 - coalesce(w.hours_worked, 0) as hours_left_to_work
from users u
cross join calendar c
left outer join
(
  select userid, date, sum(hoursworked) as hours_worked
  from employeetimeworked
  group by userid, date
) w on w.userid = u.userid and w.date = c.date
order by u.userid, c.date;
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a great start. The problem is that it returns way too much rows (about 100 000), It should only return about 31 (days in the current month). I tried to limit with date, and userID, but I don't get it to work.

Comment: For August 2020 e.g.: `where c.date >= '2020-08-01' and c.date < '2020-09-01'`. For current  month e.g.: `where year(c.date) = year(getdate()) and month(date) = month(getdate())`. For user #2: `and u.userid = 2`.

Comment: I tried that, and also tried to limit it for only a certain user (userId 2), but I still get about 200 000 rows. I think the cross join might add too much rows.
My query: 
select   
  c.date,
  u.ID, 
  8 - coalesce(w.hours_worked, 0) as hours_left_to_work
from [dbo].[User] u
cross join calendar c
left outer join
(
  select ID, date, sum(durationHours) as hours_worked
  from TimeLog  
  group by ID, date
) w on w.ID = u.Id  
and u.Id = 2
and w.date = c.date
AND c.date >= '2020-08-01' and c.date <= '2020-08-31'
order by c.date, u.ID;

Comment: Because you tied the conditions to the `ON` clause for the outer join. You want a `WHERE` clause instead. Don't `AND` the conditions to the `ON` clause, they have nothing to do with which rows you want to outer join or not.

Answer (score 0):

This query seem to have done it for me:

```
select * from (select c.Date, 8 - coalesce(sum(t.durationHours),0) hours_left_to_work 
from Calendar c
left join TimeLog t on t.Date = c.Date
where c.date >= '2020-08-01' and c.date <= '2020-08-31'
group by c.Date) as q1
where q1.hours_left_to_work IS NOT NULL
AND q1.hours_left_to_work > 0;
```

TimeLog = EmployeeTimeWorked